# How to update the data permanently in my flutter project?

Tags: flutter

I have made an app, that basically suggests some music artists and some of their top songs to the user. I want to add a feature that would allow the user to mark some songs as their favorite and I also want to show all the marked as favorite songs on a separate screen. In my flutter project, I have created a class Data in a file "data.dart" which has all the data that all the screens use. In "data.dart", I have a list of `Map<String, Object>` that has all the songs and each Map has a 'favorite' key which is initially set to false.

```
var allSongs = [
...
    {
      'url':
          'https://open.spotify.com/track/3E6iea9uEmB7gRru4lyP6h?si=b062300e24cf47d8',
      'name': 'Stop this train',
      'time': '4:45',
      'image':
          'https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F20%2F2017%2F01%2Fjohn-mayer-wave-one-2000.jpg',
      'id': 'jm',
      'favorite': false,
    },
...
];
```

I have added a button below each song Widget that is supposed to allow the user to mark the song as their favorite. I call addToFavs(val) (a function) that is called whenever the button is pressed.

```
InkWell(
   onTap: () {
      addToFavs(val);
   },
   child: Icon(
      Icons.favorite,
      color: color,
      size: 30,
   ),
),
```

In addToFavs(), I want to access the list allSongs in Data class, and I want to change the value of 'favorite' key for the specific song that user has selected.
This is how my addToFavs() function looks like

```
void addToFavs(Map<String, Object> info) {
    setState(() {
//here I am finding the index of the song that the user wants to mark as favorite
      int index = Data().allSongs.indexWhere((element) {
        return info['name'] == element['name'];
      }); 
      if (Data().allSongs[index]['favorite'] == false) {
        Data().allSongs[index]['favorite'] = true;
        color = Colors.red;
      } else {
        Data().allSongs[index]['favorite'] = false;
        color = Colors.white;
      }
    });
  }
```

And then when I go to my favorites screen, I finding all the Maps that have favorite key as true in allSong list.

```
var favorites = Data().allSongs.where((val) {
  return val['favorite'] == true;
});
```

but I don't see the songs that I have marked as favorite. I think the data is being temporarily changed in the Data class and when I go to favorite screen the data is set to what it was before.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you storing the data somewhere? Like database or shared_preference?

Comment: @EbenezerNikabou I store all the data in a class Data that is in my lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you call Data(), a new instance of Data is returned. Instead of doing this way, you can declare your allSongs variable static. This way you can call it like this : `Data.allSongs` (Notice Data without parenthesis).

```
static var allSongs = [
...
    {
      'url':
          'https://open.spotify.com/track/3E6iea9uEmB7gRru4lyP6h?si=b062300e24cf47d8',
      'name': 'Stop this train',
      'time': '4:45',
      'image':
          'https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F20%2F2017%2F01%2Fjohn-mayer-wave-one-2000.jpg',
      'id': 'jm',
      'favorite': false,
    },
...
];
```

But unless you store your data in a database or a shared_preference, changes made to your data will be lost on next launch of the app.

Comment: But when I call Data.allSongs it shows an error everywhere except in my Favorites class, the error is : Instance member 'allSongs' can't be accessed using static access.

Comment: A static variable can only be accessed in a static context. This means that all your functions using Data.allSongs must also be declared static.

Comment: By "all your functions", i mean all your functions in the same class.

Comment: Yeah i understood that but when I mark all those function static for example: addToFavs() as a static function then I am not able to use setState() inside that function

Comment: I am also using Data().allSongs in my build function so that I will have to mark it as a static function, Is there any other better way to implement this marked as a favorite that you can suggest?